# This can not be done in Dota 2 tournaments?

Tags: dota-2

Is it true that in every professional tournament of Dota 2 , two teams cannot choose the same hero? And all your teammates also cannot choose the same hero?. In other words we MUST use 10 distinct heroes in total for each game ? For example if I use Invoker then all other players including my teammates are not allowed to play Invoker?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**That's correct.** In most Dota 2 game modes, duplicate hero selections are **not allowed**. This includes Captain's Mode, which is the the primary mode used in tournaments.

The exception is [Mid Only mode](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Game_modes#Private_Lobbies), which can only be played in private lobbies. In Mid Only mode,

> Creeps only spawn in the middle lane. Duplicate heroes allowed.

Comment: If I use Invoker and my opponents also use Invoker , may be allowed in some modes ?

Comment: @PinkWhale No. The only exception to this, as I noted, is Mid Only mode (sometimes called "same hero only mid" mode).

Comment: Is it interesting to see Invoker vs Invoker , Your Invoker against my Invoker , and see who's the best Invoker ?

Comment: In most Dota 2 game modes, duplicate hero selections are not allowed. This already mention above..... This is Dota2 not League of Legend.....

Comment: Ryu vs Ryu , Ken vs Ken...  you know?

Comment: @PinkWhale while mirror matches in some games are compelling, the large variety of heroes, played exclusively, has always been a feature. Drafting, counter-picking, and hero variety are more heavily valued than "maining" a hero, or mirror matchups. Before all-pick was added to DotA, Sentinel players could only pick among the Sentinel heroes, and Scourge only the Scourge heroes. Mirrors in a moba, to my knowledge, were an invention of League of Legends and don't have a place in classic Dota gameplay.

Comment: Also, in the "lore" of the gamemode-what there is of it-there is only "one" Invoker, so  there also is the benefit of keeping the heroes unique and "special."